# can jcarousel work with database also?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, c#-4.0, jcarousel

Hi coder i search a lot but didn't find any thing related to **jcarousel** working with database so i came here to ask your help i have a page in which im using **jcarousel**

- css
- js

File Now after using this when i put text in list it work fine but in case when i use fetch text from database and and put that in list it show only the first 3 record and when i click on next button in didnt work means it will not show next text...for example i want like in this link see example number 4

[Example4](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified)
Here is my code which is working:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Carousel - jCarousel Examples</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_shared/css/style.css">

    <link href="../../jcarousel.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="../../jcarousel.responsive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Responsive Carousel</h1>                       
        <p>This example shows how to implement a responsive carousel. Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
            <div class="jcarousel">                
                <ul>
                  <li>Hello</li>
                  <li>Make it</li>
                  <li>Quick</li>
                  <li>or</li>
                  <li>you are</li>
                  <li>Fired</li>
                  <li>Understand</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

            <p id="images" class="jcarousel-pagination"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but in case if i use database to move after 3 text; its not working this is my code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <p>This example shows how to implement a responsive carousel. Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
           <div id="jc2" class="jcarousel-wrapper">
              <div class="jcarousel">
                 <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <ul>
                           <li>
                            <asp:Label ID="imagename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>                                           
              </div>
                <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

                <p id="imagename" class="jcarousel-pagination"></p>
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my code behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from Image_Master";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        rptImages.DataSource = ds;
        rptImages.DataBind();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('An Error occurred. Administrator has been notified..!');</script>");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys understand my question if any query related to code please ask i need your help. thanks in advance !!!

Comment: if there are anothor way other then jcarousel or any other document related to it please send me that too thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably is not working because your Repeater is not make the format of HTML that Carousel De-mystified ask for.

This is the html that is waiting for:

```
<div class="slider1">
  <div class="slide"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
  .....
</div>
```

and your repeater must be as:

```
<div class="jcarousel">
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="slide"><img src='/images/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image_Name") %>'  /></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>                                           
</div>
```

On this code snipped please make sure that the names, id, image path are correct with your css, javascript code and paths.

To answer and to the main question, any javascript library is irrelative to server side programming and database. Any javascript library is usually ask for a specific html format, or a specific data format. If you give that from code behind then you make it work.

Comment: that what i m asking is that in jcarousel i can use database or not as far your code is concern its not working as this an img tag

Comment: in place of reapter can i bind it with any other tag and bind it on code behind

Comment: @Amitesh I do not understand you. This code is an example, the idea is what is count, can you understand the idea behind that ? If yes then you can make it work.